# How to connect remote Oracle database in Django without Oracle installation on current server?

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I want to connect to Oracle database with Django. It requires cx_Oracle module. When I tried to install cx_Oracle, it required Oracle to be install on current server.

```
[root@localhost cx_Oracle-5.2]# /opt/python2.7/bin/python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 170, in <module>
    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
```

But actually I don't need Oracle on this server, my Oracle server is remote. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sure you need just oracle client libraries. Not all software, just client software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).

cx_Oracle uses this to make the connection to your database.

Comment: For Linux (my requirement) you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html). An oracle account/login (free) is required.